# How to use ejs with json data?

Tags: html, node.js, ejs

I want to use a json to read my videos and then display them using ejs, but I get an error:

```
>> 320|             <% video.videos.forEach(function(video) { %>
video is not defined
```

I've used the same approach for the items.json and I did not have this problem, if needed I can upload the code for displaying the items and the items.json too.
HTML:

```
<ul class="splide__list">
            <% video.videos.forEach(function(video) { %>
            <li class="splide__slide">
              <a href="<%= video.href %>" data-lity>
                <img class="thumbnail" data-splide-lazy="<%= video.src %>" alt="<%= video.alt %>">
              </a>
              <p><%= video.desc %></p>
            </li>
            <% }) %>
          </ul>
```

Node js:

```
app.all('/', function (req, res) {
    var items, videos;
    //read shop items
    fs.readFile('items.json', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).end();
        } else {
            items = JSON.parse(data);
        }
    });
    // read videos
    fs.readFile('video.json', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).end();
        } else {
            videos = JSON.parse(data);
        }
    });
    
        res.render('index.ejs', {
            items: items,
            videos: videos
       });
    
});
```

My video.json:

```
{
    "videos":[
        {
            "href":"media/video.mp4",
            "src":"thumbnails/thumbnail2.png",
            "alt":"video with 1",
            "desc":"desc1"
        },
        {
            "href":"media/video3.mp4",
            "src":"thumbnails/thumbnail3.png",
            "alt":"video with 2",
            "desc":"desc2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Typo: You pass the EJS `videos` but you try to read `video`.

Comment: Oh, and they are undefined too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `fs.readFile` is async, whereas you call the `render` function without waiting for them, so you have no warranty that you will have the content read into memory. To solve the problem you can either move your `render` call into callback or use `async/await` to handle async code. I will show you the example with `async/await`.

```
app.all('/', function (req, res) {
    try {
        const items = await fs.promises.readFile('items.json').then(JSON.parse);
        const videos = await fs.promises.readFile('videos.json').then(JSON.parse);
        res.render('index.ejs', { items, videos });

    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).end();
    }
});
```

And yes you are passing `videos` whereas in template you access the `video` variable so change that to the `videos` too.

Comment: Thank you. The main problem was how I was reading the files, using await did the trick. And of course, the variable names.